# How to fix this Bezier drawing code so that it draws a smooth curve from the start

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a `UIBezierPath` to draw a quad curve between the points of touch of my `UIPanGesture`. This works, however, a problem arises within the first few touch points where the Bezier's `currentPoint`, the control point, and the end point overlap. This results in a straight line being drawn through the points rather than a curve.

Here is my code:

```
@objc
private func pan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let currentPoint = gesture.location(in: self)
    let midpoint = calculateMidpoint(point1: previousPoint, point2: currentPoint)
   
    if gesture.state == .began {
        bezierPath.move(to: currentPoint)
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
        bezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: midpoint, controlPoint: previousPoint)
    }
    
    previousPoint = currentPoint
    
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Here is some sample output of the `bezierPath.currentPoint`, `previousPoint` and `midpoint`:

```
//bezierPath.currentPoint, previousPoint, midpoint
(191.0, 69.0), (191.0, 69.0), (184.0, 70.0)
(184.0, 70.0), (177.0, 71.0), (177.0, 71.0)
(177.0, 71.0), (177.0, 71.0), (170.0, 71.0)
(170.0, 71.0), (163.0, 71.0), (150.5, 71.0) <- This is the part where it starts to act normal
(150.5, 71.0), (138.0, 71.0), (130.5, 68.0)
(130.5, 68.0), (123.0, 65.0), (119.75, 62.0)
(119.75, 62.0), (116.5, 59.0), (115.0, 54.75)
```

How can I prevent this and draw a normal curve?

Comment: You can add a 'delta' parameter which skips over couple of points, using either position difference, or time difference, between consecutive points. This will also avoid too many points being registered and used for drawing and hence perform better.

Comment: @lukya I have tried skipping the first 3 points, but it just results in a "slightly bent" line. Performance doesn't seem to be an issue with this, it draws really quickly even if I fill the screen up with lines

Comment: From the data you've provided, for problematic sets, at least 2 out of 3 (previous, mid, current) points are *same*. In such cases you can just skip the drawing and just update *previous point*.